# properties file not found within web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications, web

I am trying to invoke a Method present within a JAR file from my Web Application (A simple Servlet Application). Below is the code that method is using for accessing the properties file:

```
InputStream inputStream = 
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
                       .getResourceAsStream("demo.properties");

properties.load(inputStream);
```

When this method is invoked using my Web Application, I am getting this `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
```

Possible reason for this exception is: My Web Application is not able to find the `demo.properties` file, hence the `inputStream` is `NULL` and this exception is thrown.

Please let me know:

1. How to resolve this exception.
2. Do I need to place the properties file manually within my Web Based Application? If yes then where exactly where to place this `demo.properties` file in my Web Application for resolving this exception.

Comment: Where is the `demo.properties` currently place within the jar?

Comment: A `src` folder is a project folder. Where is the file within the generated `.jar`?

Comment: Its in the `root` directory. If I open the `jar` using a decompiler then I can see it in the root directory (i,e, not within any package)

Comment: Then what you have should be fine.

Comment: A decompiler?  Isn't it a zip file?

Comment: @Brandon And a decompiler will open the zip archive (and do decompile class files, of course)

Comment: I think you are using the wrong class loader.  System class loader won't (generally) see your web app classes, but only deals with core Java classes like java.lang.*, java.util.*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system class loader only knows about the core Java libraries, for example, those in java.lang.*, java.util.*, etc.

You want to load the properties file using the same class loader which looks at that JAR file, which is probably the same class loader that loaded your class.

Try something like this:

```
public class PropertyFileTest {
    public void loadProperties() {
        InputStream inputStream = PropertyFileTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/demo.properties");

        properties.load(inputStream);
        // do something with properties to see if it worked or not.
    }
}
```

Note that I used Class.getResourceAsStream, which will use that class's class loader for you, per:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: What I can understand from your comment is: My Web Application is using the `<ClaccName>.class.getResourceAsStream` loader for loading the class files present inside the jar, hence the jar file should also use the same class for loading the properties fiel - Correct?

Comment: I am saying that the class loader which loaded your class *should* be the same class loader which can load the properties file.  The system class loader knows nothing about your JAR file, and therefore knows nothing of your class OR properties file.

Comment: I believe that I am confused!!! I am accessing the `properties` file from a jar file. My `Web Application` is accessing the jar file by invoking the jar file method (I am not invoking the properties file directly in my web application, rather I am invoking it using the jar file itself).

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by "invoking the properties file" or by "invoking the jar file method".  Have you tried the approach above to see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it working with your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The class loaders interprete the passed string as absolute path, hence as if it were `/demo.properties` (but never use the heading slash for `ClassLoader.getResource`). So open the war and look for `/WEB-INF/classes/demo.properties`. This must be case sensitive.

You might (in general) be interested in alternatives:

- `MyServletClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/demo.properties")` -- better;
- `ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.get("demo");`
- Using Servlet's init parameters in `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that I tried to express with "as if it were" and "but never use the heading slash for ClassLoader".

Comment: In that case you could do `SomeJarClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/demo.properties")`. The difference being that a ClassLoader is in some hierarchy from class loaders searching a class path (several jars), whereas using the class directly deals with one jar, is more directly.

Comment: Ok so it means you are asking me to change the way I am accessing the properties file in my Jar file currently. I need to use the `ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream` method rather than using the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()                 .getResourceAsStream` method right? Please confirm if I get you correctly.

Comment: Just like the answer below

Comment: Yes, btw there seems to be a comment warning for the system class loader too. I think @Brandon indeed deserves an Accepted if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, open a chat with Brandon. Unfortunately I must leave soon. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

ClassLoader does not identified which properties file location.

Use this code:

```
String path  = AbcServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("abc.properties").getFile().toString();
path = path.replace("%20", " ");
File f = new File(path);
```